# Python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isDigit'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

Here is my code

```
input = raw_input("Please enter a number")  
print input.isDigit()
```

when I feed in the input, 7 into the interpreter it throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isDigit'
```

This makes no sense since `isDigit` is a built in function and is for strings. I am using python 2.7 and I am using JetBrains Pycharm so could it be the IDE I'm using?

Comment: no str method uses camel case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`D` must be in small letter(*lowercase letter*).

```
print input.isdigit()
```

And don't use in-built keywords as variable names.

```
>>> inp = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
Please enter a number: 5
>>> print inp.isdigit()
True
```

Comment: You'll get it tomorrow through IPO's speed post!

Answer (score 0):

```
var= '10'
if(var.isdigit()):
    print "has only digits"
else:
    print "has something else"
```

you are using isdigit() method incorrectly, remember python is case sensitive and you must use lowercase d in isdigit().